# Selenium with webdriver error & printing null in NoneType case

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I want to crowling in a bank site but google chrome driver doesn't work.
And I want to print as 'null' if the type is 'NoneType' 
I wrote this code in jupyter notebook(anaconda3).

I tried to solve this problem using 'if...else...'

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from urllib.request import urlopen

from selenium import webdriver 

driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver.exe') html_dr = driver.execute_script('return document.body.innerHTML') #question

url_base = 'https://www.kebhana.com/cont/mall/mall08/mall0805/index.jsp?_menuNo=62608'

html = urlopen(url_base) soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

soup

print(soup.find_all('li', 'item type1'))

len(soup.find_all('li', 'item type1'))

from urllib.request import urljoin

name = [] url_add = [] period = [] strong = [] term = []

list_soup = soup.find_all('li', 'item type1')

for item in list_soup: name.append(item.find('a').get_text()) url_add.append(urljoin(url_base, item.find('a')['href'])) #question # # #'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text' #if item is not None: #period.append(item.find(class_='period').get_text()) #strong.append(item.find('strong')) #term.append(item.find(class_='term')) #else: #print("null")

url_add[:5]

name[:5]

period[:23]

strong[:23]

import pandas as pd

data = {'Name':name, 'URL':url_add} df = pd.DataFrame(data) df.head() df.to_csv('./hana_list.csv', sep=',', encoding='EUC-KR')

df['URL'][0]

html = urlopen(df['URL'][0]) soup_tmp = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser") soup_tmp

print(soup_tmp.find('dl', 'prodcutInfo'))

print(soup_tmp.find('div', 'exist_table'))

print(soup_tmp.find(class_='tbl_tbldiv'))
```

'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'

Comment: please indent your code properly. Also, explain what "doesn't work" entails. Are there error messages? If so, include the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling 'get_text' twice. You have put in an error check for one of them but not the other.

```
for item in list_soup: 
    name.append(item.find('a').get_text())    #<--- you may also need to check item for not None here
    url_add.append(urljoin(url_base, item.find('a')['href'])) 
    if item is not None: 
        period.append(item.find(class_='period').get_text())   #<--- you are checking item for not None here
        strong.append(item.find('strong')) 
        term.append(item.find(class_='term')) 
    else: 
        print("null")
```

Or, perhaps you are checking the wrong thing. You might need to check  `item.find(class_='period') is not None` rather than just `if item is not None`.